# Lightning Datatable: How to replace button with a lightning badge in a row on click?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, button

In each row of the lightning datatable, I have a button. I want to replace the button with a lightning badge when an user clicks on the button. I wonder, how to implement this?

**JS**

```
    @track COLUMNS = [
    
          {
            label: "Name",
            type: "text",
        },
            {
              label: "Accept",
              type: "button",
              typeAttributes: {
                  label: "Accept",
                  name: "buttonName",
                  variant: "brand"
              }
          }
        ];

export default class MiscRecord extends LightningElement{
@recordId;
@wire(getData, {recordId: '$recordId'})
    Data;
handleRowAction(event) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to implement a custom type as mentioned here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types